# Magento2 Save Shipment Button Missing in admin manage order

Tags: magento2, shipment

I used the Magento2 version: 2.1.0

In the admin panel when I want to go to generating Shipment I see the details of the order but **Save Shipment** and **Product Details** are missing.

And when I checked the system.log I see below error message:

**main.CRITICAL: Renderer for type "simple" does not exist.**

see the attached screenshot.

[image]

If anyone have already solved this issue, please help me to fixed this issue.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this.

I have installed the **Aitoc_PreOrders** and in this extension, I see the below error log:

> Warning: unserialize() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
>   in
>   /app/code/Aitoc/PreOrders/view/adminhtml/templates/items/column/name.phtml
>   on line 24

I just solve it and its working.